# CodeKit $pageTitle variable "undefined" - CodeKit compile issue

Tags: variables, codekit

I'm working with Foundation and compiling with CodeKit with the .kit language. Trying to use the $pageTitle variable, which I call in my _head-red.kit file as this:

```
<title><!--$pageTitle--> | David Pindrys</title>
```

It's defined in a page file as this:

```
<!--- $pageTitle = Page Title -->
```

Don't know what's up. My _head-ref.kit file is in a /partials directory, is called by the page file (successfully) which are in a /pages directory. When I attempt to compile, I get

```
Line 6 of _head-ref.kit: The variable $pageTitle is undefined.

(This action was triggered by a change to _head-ref.kit
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with Sass?

Comment: good point. removed the tag

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--- $pageTitle = Page Title -->
```

Needs to be

```
<!-- $pageTitle = Page Title -->
```

One dash too many in the opening tag

Answer (score 0):

In your _head-ref.kit add the following:

```
<title><!-- @pageTitle--> | David Pindrys</title>
```

Also, in your page do this:

```
<!-- @pageTitle : Page Title -->
<!-- @import '_head-ref' -->
```

This should works. For more information, check the following page: https://incident57.com/codekit/help.html#kit

Comment: Thanks Joshua! Will try and report back